# Data Storage in R

Tags: r

So I wrote a shiny app in R and part of the script includes calling a web service to collect data. I run the script on a daily basis to build the shiny app. I would like to show data collected from the web service over time, however the only way I know how would be to write the data to a csv file after every call to the web service and then load that csv file back into R to show how the data has changed over time. This may seem like a strange question, but is there a way to accomplish this solely in R so that the data is stored every time the script is run and new values from the web service call are apended?

Comment: Is your R session going to be running continuously? If not, you'll need a way to persist your data between sessions. Depending on how to connect to the web service you can collect the data in R. Could you give some more details?

Comment: Yes, my R session would be running continuously as the app is deployed via the Shiny runapp command. To connect to the web service I submit a POST request and the server responds with the data in JSON format. I then use the tidyjson package to parse the output and put the data into a dataframe. Do you think the only way I would be able to persist the data would be outside of R? (i.e. write the data to a CSV file or to a server and then reload the data back into R?)